# Make Swift Assume Degrees for Trigonometry Calculations

Tags: ios, swift, trigonometry

Is it possible to change a setting, property, etc in Swift for iOS so that it assumes degrees for trigonometry calculations rather than radians?

For example `sin(90)` would be evaluated to `1`.

I have:

```
let pi = 3.14 
var r2d = 180.0/pi
var d2r = pi/180
```

... but the conversions are getting really involved for some of the long trig equations.

Comment: you can create new functions that takes parameter in degrees and converts it to radians and gives back the results from the already defined functions.

Comment: "but the conversions are getting really involved for some of the long trig equations" I agree with @rakeshbs - this is why god gave you functions, so you can just convert any time automatically without doing anything "involved".

Comment: Yeah but god works in radians, not degrees.

Comment: NSUnitAngle is coming in iOS 10 https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsunitangle

Answer (score 32):

As already said in the other answers, there are no trigonometric functions in the standard library that take the arguments in degrees.

If you define your own function then you can use `__sinpi()`,
`__cospi()`, etc ... instead of multiplying by π:

```
// Swift 2:
func sin(degrees degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return __sinpi(degrees/180.0)
}

// Swift 3:
func sin(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return __sinpi(degrees/180.0)
}
```

From the [`__sinpi` manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/__sinpi.3.html) (emphasis added):

> The 
>   __sinpi()
>   function returns the sine of pi times x (measured in
>   radians).  This can be computed **more accurately** than sin(M_PI * x), because it can implicitly use as many bits of pi as are necessary to
>        deliver a well-rounded result, instead of the 53-bits to which M_PI is limited.  For large x it may
>        also be **more efficient,** as the argument reduction involved is significantly simpler.

`__sinpi()` and the related functions are non-standard, but
 available on iOS 7/OS X 10.9 and later.

**Example:**

```
sin(degrees: 180.0)       // 0
```

gives an exact result, in contrast to:

```
sin(180.0 * M_PI/180.0) // 1.224646799147353e-16
```

---

And just for fun: This is how you can define the degree-based sine function for all floating point types, including `CGFloat` with
function overloading (now updated for Swift 3):

```
func sin(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return __sinpi(degrees/180.0)
}

func sin(degrees: Float) -> Float {
    return __sinpif(degrees/180.0)
}

func sin(degrees: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(sin(degrees: degrees.native))
}
```

In the last variant, the compiler automatically infers from the 
actual type of `degrees.native` which function to call, so that this
works correctly on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Hey @MartinR `__sinpi` has got to be one of the best "pro-tips" on this whole site.  I sent over a bounty as a token of thanks.  mfg

Comment: That's an awesome & well description answer

Answer (score 7):

Adding an extension to identify the kind of value clearly would be a appropriate way to handle such a thing:

```
import Darwin // needed to get M_PI
extension Double {
  public var degrees: Double { return self * M_PI / 180 }
  public var ㎭: Double { return self * 180 / M_PI }
}
```

Pop that into a playground and see how you get the results you expect:

```
sin(90.degrees)  --> 1.0
1.㎭  -->  57.2957795130823
1.㎭.degrees --> 1.0
(M_PI / 3).㎭  -->  60.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define global functions that return the sin of a degree value. Just place the function in a swift file outside of any class.

```
func sind(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return sin(degrees * M_PI / 180.0)
}
```

So anywhere in your project you can just use:

```
sind(90) // Returns 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This runs in a playground, and provides a type-safe implementation of degree/radian units. The type definitions are freely taken from [here](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160104/005510.html) on the Swift evolution mailing list with a couple of minor syntax fixes. I wrote in some of the trig functions; the rest are a straightforward continuation of what I've shown.

```
import Cocoa

//MARK:- AngleType    
protocol AngleType: FloatLiteralConvertible, IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    var value: Double { get set }

    init(_ value: Double)
    init(_ value: Int)
    init<T: IntegerType>(integerLiteral value: T)
    init<T: FloatingPointType>(floatLiteral value: T)
}


// Implement FloatLiteralConvertible and IntegerLiteralConvertible
extension AngleType {
    init<T: IntegerType>(integerLiteral value: T) {
        self.init(value)
    }

    init<T: IntegerType>(_ value: T) {
        self.init(integerLiteral: value)
    }

    init<T: FloatingPointType>(floatLiteral value: T) {
        self.init(value)
    }

    init<T: FloatingPointType>(_ value: T) {
        self.init(floatLiteral: value)
    }
}

//MARK:- Degree
struct Degree: AngleType {
    typealias FloatLiteralType = Double
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int

    var value: Double

    init(_ value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = Double(value)
    }
}

protocol DegreeConvertible {
    init(degreeLiteral value: Degree)
}

extension Degree: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return self.value.description
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "\(self.value.description)°"
    }
}

extension Degree: RadianConvertible {
    init(radianLiteral value: Radian) {
        self.value = Double(radianLiteral:value) * 180.0 / M_PI
    }

    init(_ value: Radian) {
        self.init(radianLiteral: value)
    }
}

//MARK:- Radian
struct Radian: AngleType {
    typealias FloatLiteralType = Double
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int

    var value: Double

    init(_ value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = Double(value)
    }
}

protocol RadianConvertible {
    init(radianLiteral value: Radian)
}

extension Radian: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return self.value.description
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "\(self.value.description)㎭"
    }
}

extension Radian: DegreeConvertible {
    init(degreeLiteral value: Degree) {
        self.value = Double(degreeLiteral: value) * M_PI / 180.0
    }

    init(_ value: Degree) {
        self.init(degreeLiteral: value)
    }
}

//MARK:- Adding Conformance To Built In Types
extension FloatLiteralType: DegreeConvertible, RadianConvertible {
    init(degreeLiteral degree: Degree) {
        self = degree.value
    }

    init(radianLiteral radian: Radian) {
        self = radian.value
    }
}

extension CGFloat: DegreeConvertible, RadianConvertible {
    init(degreeLiteral degree: Degree) {
        self.init(degree.value)
    }

    init(radianLiteral radian: Radian) {
        self.init(radian.value)
    }

    init(_ degree: Degree) {
        self.init(degreeLiteral: degree)
    }

    init(_ radian: Radian) {
        self.init(radianLiteral: radian)
    }
}

func sin(value: Radian) -> Double { return sin(Double(value.value)) }
func asin(value: Double) -> Radian { return Radian(Double(asin(value))) }
func cos(value: Radian) -> Double{ return cos(Double(value.value)) }
func acos(value: Double) -> Radian { return Radian(Double(acos(value))) }


func sin(value: Degree) -> Double{ return sin(Radian(value)) }
func asin(value: Double) -> Degree { return Degree(Double(asin(value))) }
func cos(value: Degree) -> Double{ return cos(Radian(value)) }
func acos(value: Double) -> Degree { return Degree(Double(acos(value))) }

let d180: Degree = Degree(180.0)
let r180: Radian = Radian(degreeLiteral: d180)

let d0 = Degree(0.0)
let r0 = Radian(d0)

let dsin180 = sin(d180)
let rsin180 = sin(r180)
let dcos180 = cos(d180)
let rcos180 = cos(r180)

let dsin0 = sin(d0)
let rsin0 = sin(r0)
let dcos0 = cos(d0)
let rcos0 = cos(r0)

let adsin180: Degree = asin(dsin180)
let adcos180: Degree = acos(dcos180)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no setting or property to change the built-in trigonometric functions. You should just work strictly in radians if you want to simplify your expressions, or define your own `sindeg`, `cosdeg`, etc.

Each of the floating-point types has a built-in `static` member named `pi` whose value is the best approximation to π. For example: `Double.pi`, `Float.pi`, `CGFloat.pi`.

Also, sin 90˚ is 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to overload the default global method, but if you must, you can provide an alternate method signature:

```
func sin(#degrees: Double) -> Double { // Require a parameter name for method call
    let radians: Double = degrees * (M_PI / 180) // Convert to rad
    return sin(radians) // Return result of default method call with automatic conversion
}

sin(degrees: 90) // 1.0
sin(degrees: 180) // 0.0
```

However, this is really an odd way of doing it, and it would make more sense to explicitly define your own method (that's what they're for), in a similar way:

```
func sinFromDegrees(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    let radians: Double = degrees * (M_PI / 180)
    return sin(radians)
}

sinFromDegrees(90) // 1.0
sinFromDegrees(180) // 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as I use trig a lot. I found the best way was to define some functions outside of the `class ViewController`.

If you define them in any one of your .swift files just below the `imports` and just above the `class ViewController:UIViewController { }` then you can call them throughout the whole project.

So for the sin function, I named it `sindeg()` standing for "sin degrees".

```
func sindeg(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return sin(degrees * M_PI / 180.0)
    }
```

So this takes your degrees number converts it, solves it and returns as degrees.
So all you need to do is type `sindeg(45.5)` and the result would = `0.71325045.`

Here is the others:

```
func cosdeg(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return cos(degrees * M_PI / 180.0)
}
func tandeg(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return tan(degrees * M_PI / 180.0)
}
```

arcTan here is very similar, only difference is the return formula

```
 func atanDegree(degrees: Double) -> Double {
        return atan(degrees) * 180 / M_PI
    }
```

This one is just to convert a radian value to degrees. Takes in radians, converts, returns back degrees.

```
func Convert(radians: Double) -> Double {
    return radians * 180.0 / M_PI
}
```