# How can I convert from degrees to radians?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, macros

I am trying to convert this `Obj-C` code to `Swift` code but I don't know what the equivalent of this code should be ?

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)((M_PI * degrees)/180)
```

I googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift)

But I don't understand how to convert that in Swift in my case?

Comment: I think you are missing some code. Can you all add all relevant code? Any other defines, like degrees?

Comment: this is my swift code :http://pastebin.com/bZ4a7EVN

Comment: Can you show me you .h file?

Comment: It's a macro. You want a function.

Comment: ultratip ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600210/294884

Answer (score 286, accepted):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1 or later**

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { CGFloat(self) * .pi / 180 }
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

---

**Playground**

```
45.degreesToRadians         // 0.7853981633974483

Int(45).degreesToRadians    // 0.7853981633974483
Int8(45).degreesToRadians   // 0.7853981633974483
Int16(45).degreesToRadians  // 0.7853981633974483
Int32(45).degreesToRadians  // 0.7853981633974483
Int64(45).degreesToRadians  // 0.7853981633974483

UInt(45).degreesToRadians   // 0.7853981633974483
UInt8(45).degreesToRadians  // 0.7853981633974483
UInt16(45).degreesToRadians // 0.7853981633974483
UInt32(45).degreesToRadians // 0.7853981633974483
UInt64(45).degreesToRadians // 0.7853981633974483

Double(45).degreesToRadians    // 0.7853981633974483
CGFloat(45).degreesToRadians   // 0.7853981633974483
Float(45).degreesToRadians     // 0.7853981
Float80(45).degreesToRadians   // 0.78539816339744830963
```

If you would like to make the binary integer return a floating point type instead of always returning a CGFloat you can make a generic method instead of a computed property:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    func degreesToRadians<F: FloatingPoint>() -> F {  F(self) * .pi / 180 }
}
```

---

```
let radiansDouble: Double = 45.degreesToRadians()   // 0.7853981633974483
let radiansCGFloat: CGFloat = 45.degreesToRadians() // 0.7853981633974483
let radiansFloat: Float = 45.degreesToRadians()     // 0.7853981
let radiansFloat80: Float80 = 45.degreesToRadians() // 0.78539816339744830963
```

Comment: Shouldn't you extend `CGFloat`?

Comment: @Zorayr updated to Swift 3 and extending FloatingPoint now extends them all

Comment: Actually, in Swift 3 you can use the Measurement types and you don't need to know the conversion formula at all!

Comment: **NOTE HOWEVER** this superpro tip ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600210/294884

Comment: Voting down without a reason doesn't make any sense. Post a comment

Comment: @Fattie how can that be used to improve this answer?

Comment: @BenLeggiero The only thing I can think of would be a generic method on BinaryInteger to allow it to return a FloatingPoint type instead of always returning CGFloat

Answer (score 74):

This is not identically what you asked, but in Swift 3 / iOS 10, you can use the Measurement type and do the conversion without knowing the formula!

```
let result = Measurement(value: 45, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
    .converted(to: .radians).value
```

Comment: Amazing @matt at work again, thanks! Only iOS 10 unfortunately.

Comment: interesting thing that 
let radians = CGFloat(30.3 * .pi / 180.0)

let radians2 = Measurement(value: 30.3, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
    .converted(to: .radians).value
will be different: 0.5288347633542818 and 0.5288345742619878

Comment: and sure "'Measurement' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer"

Answer (score 43):

Apple provides these [GLKit functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMathUtils/index.html) for conversion:

```
func GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_ degrees: Float) -> Float
func GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(_ radians: Float) -> Float
```

Comment: GLKit is going off stage soon, since now it is Metal's world, bye GL. As porting iPad app to Mac, GLKit is not longer supported!.

Answer (score 19):

```
let angle = 45° // angle will be in radians, 45 is in degrees
```

Compiles under **Swift 3**. Still keep all values, do all calculations in radians with CGFloats..., but make the code more readable with the constants in degrees. **For example: 90°** 
The ° sign will magically do the degrees to radians conversion.

How to set this up:

Define and use a postfix operator for the **°** sign. This operator will do the conversion from degrees to radians.
This example is for Ints, extend these also for the Float types if you have the need.

```
postfix operator °

protocol IntegerInitializable: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
  init (_: Int)
}

extension Int: IntegerInitializable {
  postfix public static func °(lhs: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(lhs) * .pi / 180
  }
}
```

Some examples of usage:

```
let angle = 45°

contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45°)

let angle = 45
contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle°)
```

Warning!

It is too easy to use this conversion twice (on a value already in radians by mistake), you will get a very small number as the result, and seemingly the resulting angle will be always zero... DO NOT use ° on the same value twice (do not convert twice)!!:

```
// OBVIOUSLY WRONG!
let angle = 45°° // ° used twice here

// WRONG! BUT EASY TO MISS
let angle = 45° // ° used here
contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle°) // ° also used here
```

Comment: `IntegerInitializable` protocol is pointless. Int already conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`

Comment: Btw You can make this operator generic to support any Integer and return any Floating Point as well. `public extension FixedWidthInteger {
    postfix static func °<T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: Self) -> T {
    T(lhs) * .pi / 180
  }
}`

Comment: And before you comment about it when creating a generic method you would need to explicitly set the resulting type if the compiler cannot infer the resulting type `let angle: CGFloat = 45°`. But it is not needed where it expects a `CGFloat` or any `FloatingPoint` type `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45°)`

Answer (score 12):

Also, to convert fron radians to degrees (if anyone stumbles upon this on google):

```
var degrees = radians * (180.0 / M_PI)
```

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient and accurate way to convert a Double between degrees and radians:

```
import Foundation

extension Double {
    var radians: Double { return Measurement(value: self, unit: UnitAngle.degrees).converted(to: UnitAngle.radians).value }
    var degrees: Double { return Measurement(value: self, unit: UnitAngle.radians).converted(to: UnitAngle.degrees).value }
}
```

The Foundation team at Apple addressed this problem long ago by developing a solution that surpasses all others:

[Measurements and Units - WWDC 2016, Session 238](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/238eemv232k9lp2px30/238/238_hd_measurements_and_units.mp4?dl=1)

Answer (score 3):

You're no longer limited to ASCII characters when creating variable names, so how about this using π (alt-p):

```
typealias RadianAngle = CGFloat

let π = RadianAngle(M_PI)
let π_x_2 = RadianAngle(M_PI * 2)
let π_2 = RadianAngle(M_PI_2)
let π_4 = RadianAngle(M_PI_4)

extension RadianAngle {
    var degrees: CGFloat {
        return self * 180 / π
    }
    init(degrees: Int) {
        self = CGFloat(degrees) * π / 180
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let quarterCircle = RadianAngle(degrees: 90)
print("quarter circle = \(quarterCircle) radians")
// quarter circle = 1.5707963267949 radians

let halfCircle = π
print("half circle = \(halfCircle.degrees) degrees")
// half circle = 180.0 degrees
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

You can write global generic functions:

```
public func radians<T: FloatingPoint>(degrees: T) -> T {
    return .pi * degrees / 180
}

public func degrees<T: FloatingPoint>(radians: T) -> T {
    return radians * 180 / .pi
}
```

Example:

```
let cgFloat: CGFloat = 23.0
let double: Double = 23.0
let float: Float = 23.0
let int: Int = 23

let cgf = radians(degrees: cgFloat) // 0.4014 CGFloat
let d = radians(degrees: double)    // 0.4014 Double
let f = radians(degrees: float)     // 0.4014 Float
let i = radians(degrees: int)       // compile error
```

In case when you don't want to extension all your floating types like this

```
extension FloatingPoint { ... }
```

Comment: Why not simply `return .pi * degrees / 180` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus because `T` is `FloatingPoint` type and 180 is `Int` type. In swift you cannot do calculations on different types.

Comment: You are wrong. Swift can infer the type. It behaves exactly the same as if you were extending the FloatingPoint type. 180 can be any thing. not necessarily an Int

Comment: The same applies to your `.pi` you don't need to call `T.pi` because the compiler knows you are returning `T` so it infers that `.pi`is a static property on `T` (which represents a `FloatingPoint` in this case).

Comment: Swift knows that `.pi` is `T`, because `FloatingPoint` implements `.pi` and 180 by default is `Int`. In Swift you cannot do calculations `Double` with `Int`, `Float` with `Int`, `FloatingPoint` with `Int`, you need to cast 180 to generic `FloatingPoint` type in order to get valid expression.

Comment: Why don’t you simply test it in a playground. Anyway fell free to keep your answer as you wish if you insist that T initializer is needed there.

Comment: You are right, it works for .pi * degrees / 180 (180 is `Int`), but it doesn't work for .pi * degrees / 180.0 (180.0 is `Double`). It looks like Swift can infer how to cast `Int` 180, and Swift cannot infer how to cast `Double` 180.0 to `FloatingPoint`

Comment: FloatingPoint conforms to ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral that’s why you can write 180 there

Comment: 180.0 needs T because T is not necessarily a Double. It can be Any floating point type. You initialize a new one from your double 180.0

Comment: Btw check this `extension Int: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    public init(floatLiteral value: FloatLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
let integer: Int = 2.5  // 2`

Comment: Yep, `Int.init(floatLiteral: 2.5)` is similar to write `Int.init(2.5)`, in first and second case parameter is `BinaryFloatingPoint`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the same principle @t1ser mentioned above, but create an extension of `CGFloat` to make it easier to use decimals for the degree as well (so you could have a 23.4 degrees, for example):

```
extension CGFloat {
    func degrees() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180
    }

    init(degrees: CGFloat) {
        self = degrees.degrees()
    }
}
```

Using it would be pretty easy as well (mainly because I personally didn't know how to type °  - in case you didn't either, it's `option+shift+8` btw):

```
let degreesToConvert: CGFloat = 45.7
.
.
.
let convertedDegrees = degreesToConvert.degrees()
```

Or to use the initialiser:

```
let convertedDegrees = CGFloat(degrees: 45.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to import `SwiftUI` or if you are already using it you could use the `Angle` type to convert between angle units, eg.:

```
import SwiftUI

let radians = Angle(degrees: 45).radians
```

This will convert from `Double` to `Double`.