# How to convert a computed value to a literal for enum initialization

Tags: swift, enums

I've run into an issue with my enums in that I want to initialize a case to the double value of `PI / 180`.  Is there a way to take this calculated value via a constant or some funky magic and turn it into a literal so that I can initialize the enum?

I would prefer not to have to do a `3.14....` - I would rather use the actual compiler and hardware computed representation of this value.

So my 1st attempt was:

```
public enum ANGLE_TYPE : Double {

    case DEGREES = Double(CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0))
    case RADIANS = 1.0
}
```

I keep getting the error **Raw value for enum case must be a literal**

Second attempt was :

```
public enum ANGLE_TYPE : Double {
  let d : Double = Double(CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0))

case DEGRESS = d
}
```

and i get the same error.

Could somebody please tell me how to go about doing this.

Comment: What part about the error do you not understand?  You can't use a calculated value for the raw value...

Comment: Do you know what "literal" means?  You have to use a literal value.  Not a variable, not a calculated value, a literal value.

Comment: This is a valid question and does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus i know how t convert from D2R - the question is related to the enum and literals

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only use literals for the raw values of type-backed enums.

To get this to work, you have to calculate the raw value of the calculation you're performing and paste that literal in as an approximation:

```
public enum ANGLE_TYPE : Double {
    case DEGREES = 0.0174532925199433
    case RADIANS = 1.0
}
```

The only other option is to *not* have a type-backed enum and manually provide the `rawValue` property:

```
public enum ANGLE_TYPE {
    case DEGREES, RADIANS

    var rawValue: Double {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .DEGREES:
                return Double(CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0))
            case .RADIANS:
                return 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might make sense because this means you don't have the `init(rawValue:Double)` initializer, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense in this case probably.

As a side note, this all caps thing is really unnecessary.  I'd much prefer something more like this:

```
public enum AngleMeasureUnit {
    case Degrees, Radians
}
```