# Objective-C compatible Swift enum with NSUIntegerMax

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, uint

I'm translating some code from Objective-C to Swift.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SomeType) {
    SomeTypeZero = 0,
    SomeTypeOne = 1,
    SomeTypeMax = NSUIntegerMax
};
```

However UInt.max gives me a compiler error: "Raw value for enum case must be a literal."

```
@objc enum SomeType: UInt {
    case zero = 0
    case one = 6
    case max = UInt.max
}
```

So what's going on here and how can I translate it, with backwards compatibility?

Comment: check this thread out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215825/how-to-convert-a-computed-value-to-a-literal-for-enum-initialization

Comment: So it's because those values are defined on compile time instead of runtime?

Answer (score 0):

UInt.max is a value which is defined at runtime. However to be a value of an enumeration the value needs to be defined at compile time.