# Mathematical - Swift - Degrees and Radian

Tags: swift

I've been going through the documentation but could not seem to find an answer.

How do I use mathematical functions like Rad() and Deg() to convert degrees to radians also the rad to deg?

Answer (score 1):

Defining your own functions is trivial, i.e.:

```
func degToRad(deg : Double) -> Double {
    return deg / 180 * M_PI
}
```

Or put it in an extension.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to @Eiko's answer, if you're using OpenGL, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231934/1804409) tells us about this `GLKMathDegreesToRadians` function. You can see documentation for this function [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMathUtils/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMathDegreesToRadians).