# Swift SpriteNode Initial Angle

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I'm trying to set the initial angle of my sprite to be 90 degrees. I don't want to call an action, is there a way of setting the angle parameter of a sprite as you do with the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### zRotation

You can use the `zRotation` property of `SKNode` which accept radiants

### Degrees to Radiants

[There's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179692/how-can-i-convert-from-degrees-to-radians) a useful extension for that

```
extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * M_PI / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Double { return Double(self) * 180 / M_PI }
}

sprite.zRotation = CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians)
```

[image]

### From the Api Doc

> The Euler rotation about the z axis (in radians).
>
> The default value is 0.0, which indicates no rotation. A positive value indicates a counterclockwise rotation. When the coordinate system is rotated, it affects the node and its descendants. The rotation affects the node’s frame property, hit testing, rendering, and other similar characteristics.

---

*The Yoshi's Island image comes form [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshi%27s_Island#/media/File:Yoshi%27s_Island_(Super_Mario_World_2)_box_art.jpg).*

Comment: Parameters are in Radians and not degrees, so 90 won't work. Instead I put M_PI_2

Comment: Shouldn't the extension return a `CGFloat` instead of a `Double`?

Comment: Where, in the code of a game, should an extension to Int be?