# Math function returns wrong value

Tags: swift

I have the following calculations:

```
let sinX = sin(150.0) //returns -0,71487
let cosY = cos(150.0) // returns 0,699250
```

But the real values for sinX = 0,5 and for cosY = -0,86.

Does anybody know where is the error?

Comment: Related: [Make Swift Assume Degrees for Trigonometry Calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598307/make-swift-assume-degrees-for-trigonometry-calculations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calculation is correct. However `sin` and `cos` take their param in radians, not degrees.

> In calculus and most other branches of mathematics beyond practical
>   geometry, angles are universally measured in radians.  One radian is
>   equal to 180/π degrees.
>
> To convert from radians to degrees, multiply by 180/π.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian

Answer (score 1):

And are you sure the sin & cos methods haven't been redefined by creating or overriding the default methods. That happens in programming. If so, you might want to re-check your operation.