# Trigonometry Function (cos) Returning Different Value to a Calculator

Tags: swift, trigonometry

When I use the cos function on a calculator cos(0) = 1, cos(90) = 0 cos(180) = -1 and cos(270) = 0. However I don't know how to produce these results in my code. The result I receive in my code are either 1 or -1, but never 0. Below is what I have try and none give me the same results as a calculator, what am I missing?

```
print(cos(0))               // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
print(cos(90))              // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
print(cos(180))             // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
print(cos(270))             // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"

print(cos(M_PI*0))          // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*1))          // returns -1
print(cos(M_PI*2))          // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*3))          // returns -1

print(cos(M_PI*0))          // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*90))         // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*180))        // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*270))        // returns 1

print(cos(M_PI/M_PI-1))     // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI+89))    // returns -0.44
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI+179))   // returns -0.59
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI+269))   // reutnrs 0.98
```

The below repeats through the results of 1, 0, -1, 0:

```
var x: Double = 0
while x < 100 {
    print(Int(cos(M_PI*(x*0.5))))
    x = x + 1
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598307/make-swift-assume-degrees-for-trigonometry-calculations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Darwin` trig functions work in Radians.

## Issue 1.1

```
print(cos(0))               // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
print(cos(90))              // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
print(cos(180))             // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
print(cos(270))             // receiver error "Ambiguous use of 'cos'"
```

These are ambiguous because there are two version of cos, which these two types:

- `(Double) -> Double`
- `(Float) -> Float`

Both `Double` and `Float` conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, so both can be expressed by an `Int`. It's ambiguous as to which of the two types the `Int` should express.

If you want the `Double` version, you can call it with:

- `cos(0 as Double)`
- `cos(0.0)` because direct use of a floatliteral as a `Double` takes precedence over a conversion via `expressiblebyfloatliteral`.

If you want the `Float version`, you can call it with: `cos(0 as Float)`

In both cases, the ambiguity can be resolved if context provides sufficient information. For example:

```
functionThatTakesADouble(cos(0)) // will use the `(Double) -> Double` version
functionThatTakesAFloat(cos(0)) // will use the `(Float) -> Float` version
print(cos(M_PI*0)) // M_PI is a Double, so 0 is treated as a Double
```

## Issue 1.2

After resolving the type ambiguity, like so:

```
print(cos(0.0))   // 1.0
print(cos(90.0))  // -0.44807361612917
print(cos(180.0)) // -0.598460069057858
print(cos(270.0)) // 0.984381950632505
```

We get correct answers. Remember, the system trig functions work in radians.

## Issue 2

```
print(cos(M_PI*0))          // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*1))          // returns -1
print(cos(M_PI*2))          // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*3))          // returns -1
```

These are all correct values.

## Issue 3

```
print(cos(M_PI*0))          // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*90))         // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*180))        // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI*270))        // returns 1
```

These are also correct. `cos` is `1` for every even multiple of `pi` radians.

## Issue 4

```
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI-1))     // returns 1
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI+89))    // returns -0.44
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI+179))   // returns -0.59
print(cos(M_PI/M_PI+269))   // reutnrs 0.98
```

`M_PI/M_PI` is `1.0` (as a `Double`), so these cases are equivalent to the first, but with the extra type information necessary to allow the compiler to unambiguously choose `(Double) -> Double` `cos` over `(Float) -> Float`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It has pointed me in the direction I needed! Int(cos(M_PI * x)) gives me the same results as a calculator (x being a division of 0.5), so thank you for helping me get the answer!

Comment: @Jarron Something's very wrong. Why are you turning the double result of Cos into an int? Cos's output is always between -1.0 and 1.0. Converting to an int will make all values less then 0 truncated to -1, and all values above 0 but less than 1 will truncate to 0

Comment: @Jarron Firstly, to make sure we're on the same page, do you understand radians, and how to use them?

Comment: to be honest not really, but the Int(cos(M_PI * x)) returns the values I need, so I'm happy. I needed the following results 1, 0, -1, 0, repeat . Cos(0) on a calculator = 1, cos(90) = 0, cos(180) = -1, cos(270) = 0 and then it repeats the results (360, 450 and so on). These are the results I need in my code, thats why I used Int() to return either -1, 0 or 1)

Comment: @Jarron every value outside of multiples of 90 will fail. To properly compute the cos of x, where x is in degrees, you'll need to convert it to radians: cos(M_PI / 180 * x)

Comment: But how do I get cos(M_PI / 180 * x) to repeat through the results of 1, 0, -1, 0, what does x need to be increased by to get those result in that order? Because I can't figure out how to get those results without using int()

Comment: @Jarron your loop only tests multiples of 1/4 pi rad, which is equivalent to multiple of 90 degrees. All other values will have the wrong result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136598/discussion-between-alexander-and-jarron).

Answer (score -2):

For Ambiguous use of cos issue, use

```
Double(cos(90))
```

instead of `cos(90)`. You should specify the Type